# "Рыба" в значении "заготовка"

Tags: жаргонизмы

Мне не один раз приходилось слышать слово "рыба" в значении "заготовка чего-то". Например, один WEB-мастер говорил, что на заказ создаст "рыбу" сайта, то есть некий шаблон, который заказчик потом сможет наполнять сам.

Вот мне интересно, откуда взялось это выражение и почему именно рыба? И еще: надо ли в подобном значении писать это слово в кавычках?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кавычки де-юре не нужны. Значение уже стало вполне законным и включается в словари.

> > Рыба 
> > ....
> > 3. Разг.
> > То, что подготовлено для кого-л. в качестве предварительного или необходимого материала; заготовка. Доклад ещё не готов, но р. уже есть.
> > ...

(БТС Кузнецова)
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%F0%FB%E1%E0&all=x

Но если есть сомнения, что поймут правильно, то пусть будут, некоторые основания к тому еще сохранились.

Вот насчет происхождения... Сейчас не могу найти источников, но когда-то писал по этому поводу весьма обширные посты и даже заметки - на разных ресурсах, может и здесь тоже.

Самое популярное объяснение на самом деле ничего не объясняет, а только дает некоторое направление поиска. Объясняние это таково. "Рыба" пришла из языка музыкантов, у которых нотный стан с первым наброском мелодии (именно мелодии, первичной музыки, без аккомпанемента) носил название "рыбы". Почему именно он и почему именно рыбы, сказать не могу. 
Еще одна схожая "музыкальная" версия: рыбой называется первый текст, набрасываемый поэтом-песенником по заказу композитора под готовую (или готовящуюся) мелодию - проверить её на вокальное звучание, проверить соответствие размеру - и т.д. Я никакой музыкант, в предмете совсем не ориентируюсь, могу лишь подтвердить, что такое название для заготовки текста у поэтов существовало и существует. Причины тоже неизвестны, вроде бы такой текст чем-то напоминает им рыбий скелет - хребет с косточками, на которые потом нарастает текстовое и музыкальное "мясо".

Но первично ли это употребление (оба варианта) или тоже где-то позаимствовано, сказать не могу. Равно как и рассуждать на тему, могло ли оно перенестись на более широкую сферу применения.

Другие варианты (например объяснение через сетку-основу для ковровой ткани) слабее и недостоверны.

Если найду ссылки на старые обсуждения, принесу их и сюда. Но суть я изложил.

Comment: Может, потому, что нотный стан с хвостиками нот может напоминать рыбий скелет?

Comment: Бог знает...
"Не моя" тема. Мне он напоминает китайскую грамоту.

Answer (score 1):

В автобиографической книге Леонида Асанова "Другие мы" (М. 1989) "Рыбе" даётся такое определение - "условный текст, совпадающий с будущей мелодией" в качестве примера "рыбы" для рок-песни приводится такой текст:

> Абдлдзыб-дзэб-дзуб
> Абдлдзуб-дзэб-луба
> Абдлзуппа-лудзаппа-лубап

Предполагаю, что "рыбой" подобные заготовки называли из-за аналогии "сырой"-в воде-"рыба".

Comment: Кто такой Асанов? 
Мне несколько смущает пример. Обычно "рыба" это пусть и не совсем правильный, но вполне осмысленный текст с точки зрения слов и грамматики...  
  
По улице ходила большая крокодила  
Она, она, зеленная была.  
  
Или вот из студенческих воспоминаний:  
  
Ты пришла и съела маргарин.  
(Ви ар лив ин де йеоллоу сабмарин)

остальное - верно.

(+)
Посмотрел. Узнал, что это некий псковский писатель. Мне очень стыдно, но ни его фамилия, ни название его главной книги (другие на поверхности даже не упоминяются), мне ни о чем не говорят.

Comment: @behemothus, я тоже биографию писателя не знаю, да и наткнулся на его книгу совершенно случайно, но книга хорошая (по крайней мере 8 лет назад она мне понравилась), и что важно в данном контексте на основе личных воспоминаний.  Далее, в тексте, автор берётся сочинить текст песни на основе, предложенной "рыбы".
Ваши примеры "рыбы" не противоречат определению Асанова. Текст должен быть условным, а имеет он смысл или нет в этом случае не особо важно.

Comment: >Ваши примеры "рыбы" не противоречат определению Асанова  
   
Я понимаю. Дело в другом. Пример противоречит моему пониманию (ну или моему "внутреннему определению").   
  
>Текст должен быть условным, а имеет он смысл или нет в этом случае не особо важно.  
  
Текст может и не быть "условным", он должен быть понятным, запоминающимся и читаемым с письменного источнника. В этом и есть его смысл.  
А эти асановские "абдылдзыбы" забываются через десять минут после снятия наушников, если только слушавший не профессиональный барабанщик или степист с обостренным чувством ритма.

Comment: (+)
А уж с "листа" понять, где там ударения или сильные доли в принципе невозможно.

Абдлдзыб-дзэб-дзуб  
Абдлдзуб-дзэб-луба  
Абдлзуппа-лудзаппа-лубап  

- Где тут что?
   
А теперь сравните:  
  
Абдул был глуп,  
Завел он раба,  
А Коран зашвырнул на шкап.  
  
Хоть и ахинея, но запоминающаяся. На этот "размер", правда, что-то осмысленное написать очень трудно, но уж до ужина точно не забудете. 
Кстати, в исходном тексте" еще одна проблема есть - там из-за нагромождения согласных сонорные могут производить скрытый слог: Абд**ы**лдзып. Это тоже не сближает с такой "рыбой".

Comment: > я тоже биографию писателя не знаю,   
  
Да и бог с ним. Я было думал, что это я о каком мэтра непочтительно отозвался...   
    
Интересно, а у Гаспарова (а у него можно найти все обо всем) что-нить есть про нашу рыбу?!   
  
На всяк случай: Коммент этот тут последний... для продолжения разговора, если таковое понадобится, вынужден буду куда-то переместиться.  

Хотя нет... интересно, десять уже получилось...
Ну тогда можно не экономить. Спасибо Администрации.

Answer (score 0):

Кавычки, безусловно, нужны, т.к. здесь слово "рыба" явно в несвойственном значении.

Comment: Согласен, т.к. это слово является жаргонизмом "широко известным в узких кругах"и без кавычек может ввести в заблуждение человека несведущего.

Comment: Словарь Кузнецова это как раз не для узких кругов.  
Да и по сути слово (в этм значении)значении давно стало общеупотребительным.